# Spinlock implementation reasoning

Tags: c++11, boost, spinlock

I want to improve the performance of a program by replacing some of the mutexes
with spinlocks. I have found a spinlock implementation in

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/detail/spinlock_sync.hpp

which I intend to reuse. I believe this implementation is safer than simpler implementations in which threads keep trying forever like the one found here

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_spinlock.implementation

But i need to clarify some things on the yield function found here

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/detail/yield_k.hpp

First of all I can assume that the numbers 4,16,32 are arbitrary. I actually tested some other values and I have found that I got best performance in my case by using other values.

But can someone explain the reasoning behind the yield code. Specifically why do we need all three

- `BOOST_SMT_PAUSE`
- `sched_yield` and
- `nanosleep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this concept is known as "adaptive spinlock" - see e.g. https://lwn.net/Articles/271817/.

Usually the numbers are chosen for *exponential back-off*: https://geidav.wordpress.com/tag/exponential-back-off/

So, the numbers aren't arbitrary. However, which "numbers" work for your case depend on your application patterns, requirements and system resources.

The three methods to introduce "micro-delays" are designed explicitly to balance the cost and the potential gain:

- zero-cost is to spin on high-CPU, but it results in high power consumption and wasted cycles
- a small "cheap" delay might be able to prevent the cost of a context-switch while reducing the CPU load relative to a busy-spin
- a simple `yield` might allow the OS to avoid a context switch depending on other system load (e.g. if the number of threads < number logical cores)

The trade-offs with these are important for low-latency applications where the effect of a context switch or cache misses are significant.

#### TL;DR

All trade-offs try to find a balance between wasting CPU cycles and losing cache/thread efficiency.

Comment: All this being said and true, any use of a spinlock that holds the lock for more than a few cycles, or has significant contention, is a costly abuse. The adaptive spinlock may help to alleviate the symptoms, but it cannot cure the problem. So, think hard before resorting to a spinlock.